# If the intersection of a normal subgroup and the derived group is $\{e\}$, show that $N$ is a subset of $Z(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I think my reasoning is wrong, but if the intersection only contains the identity, doesn't that imply that the only commutator in $N$ is $\{e\}$, so doesn't that mean $N$ is automatically commutative? Why was it necessary to state that $N$ was a normal subgroup? Thanks!

Comment: @DonAntonio : the derived subgroup of $S_3$ is $A_3$

Comment: Oh, rats! Somehow I indeed read "derived group" but I understood "center of..." ! Thanks, deleting.

Answer (score 4):

Your argument is correct to show that $N$ is abelian (whether or not $N$ is a normal subgroup).  But to show that $N$ is in the centre of $G$ is stronger --- you have to show that every element of $N$ commutes with every element of $G$.  This will require the assumption that $N$ is normal.

Comment: For example $N=\{(), (1,2)\} \leq G=S_3 = \{ (), (1,2), (1,2,3), (2,3), (1,3,2), (1,3) \}$. $G'=\{(),(1,2,3),(1,3,2)\}$ and $N \cap G'=\{()\}$ so $N$ is abelian, but $Z(G)=\{()\}$ so $N$ is not a subgroup of the center. Indeed, $(1,2) \in N$ does not commute with any element of $G$ outside of $N$.

Answer (score 3):

(1) First, note that $\;N\lhd G\iff [N,G]\le N\;$

(2) Also, note that $\;x\in G\;$ is a central element iff $\;[x,G]=1\;$

So since $\;N\,,\,G'\lhd G\; $, we get

$$[N,G]\le[N,G']\le N\cap G'=1\iff N\le Z(G)$$

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the notations you used, do you mind letting me know what [N,G] means? Thanks!

Comment: @Rod : $$[N,G]:=\langle,[n,g]\;;\;n\in N\,,\,g\in G\;\rangle =$$the subgroup generated by all the commutators of the form $\;[n,g]\;$ ...

Comment: Why is [N,G] ≤ [N, G'] ? Shouldn't the inclusion go the other way?

Comment: It is not true that $N\le Z(G)\implies N\cap G'=1$. Consider the quaternion group, the center and the derived subgroup of the quaternion group are equal which is $\{1,-1\}$.