# If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $N \cap [G,G]=\{e\}$, then $N$ is contained in $Z(G)$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, derived-subgroup

I found an answer to this here:
[If the intersection of a normal subgroup and the derived group is $\{e\}$, show that $N$ is a subset of $Z(G)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763008/if-the-intersection-of-a-normal-subgroup-and-the-derived-group-is-e-show). However I don't really understand some of the answers given and some other aspects such as, why does,
$$N \cap [G,G]=\{e\},$$
imply that $N$ is abelian? I know it doesn't contain any commutators, but I'm not sure how the abelian property follows. Furthermore, knowing that $N$ is normal and abelian, I'm not sure how to go about showing that $N$ is contained in $Z(G)$.

Comment: Don't you mean $N\cap[G,G]=\{e\}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick any two $m,n\in N$. Then $[m,n]\in [G,G]\cap N=\{e\}$ so $[m,n]=e$, i.e. $mn=nm$.

Pick any $g\in G,n\in N$. Then $[g,n]=(gng^{-1})n^{-1}$ is a product of two elements of $N$ (note $gng^{-1}\in N$ since we assume $N\trianglelefteq G$ is normal) so $[g,n]\in [G,G]\cap N=\{e\}$. Thus $[g,n]=e$...

Comment: Then from the last point, is it enough to right multiply by $ng$? Or is there something more that needs to be done?

Comment: Yeah, $[g,n]=e$ implies $gn=ng$. Since $g$ was arbitrary, $n\in Z(G)$.